# Remove all duplicate data from a multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, duplicates, filtering

I'm trying to remove all keys with repeated numbers, I've tried some solutions posted here like the one I'm using in my script but none of it worked for my purpose.

This is my array:

There are at least 4 card IDs repeated.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_card] => 11883834
            [type] => 1
            [registed] => 1547610891
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_card] => 20311077
            [type] => 1
            [registed] => 1547610891
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id_card] => 16187903
            [type] => 3
            [registed] => 1547610891
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id_card] => 16354099
            [type] => 1
            [registed] => 1547610891
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id_card] => 21133393
            [type] => 4
            [registed] => 1547610891
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id_card] => 15452852
            [type] => 2
            [registed] => 1547610891
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id_card] => 19775869
            [type] => 2
            [registed] => 1547610891
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id_card] => 20311077
            [type] => 1
            [registed] => 1547610891
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [id_card] => 21133393
            [type] => 4
            [registed] => 1547610891
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [id_card] => 11883834
            [type] => 1
            [registed] => 1547610891
        )

)
1
```

At the moment I have something like this:

```
<?php
$array_data = array_map('unserialize', array_unique(array_map('serialize', $myArray)));
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array_data);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

With only 10 keys is working perfectly, but when it goes through this with, for example, 50, 100 keys, no longer works.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are all `id_card`, `type` and `registered` properties the same in the duplicate elements? If not, which one should be removed?

Comment: No, they won't always be the same. If it's any different, I'd like to keep the first key found.

Comment: The differences are why your current code isn't working as it compares the entire serialized array

Comment: In this case, any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the issue here is that the `array_unique` solutions expect the entire value to be equivalent - they don't just compare based on your ID field.

Instead, you probably want to loop through the array and keep track of which IDs you've seen, and only take those elements for which you haven't seen the ID before.

```
function filter_duplicate_id_cards($data) {
  $seen = array(); // To keep track of the IDs we've seen
  $filtered = array(); // Will hold the result

  foreach($data as $item) {
    if(array_key_exists($item['id_card'], $seen)) {
      // We already encountered this id card before.
      continue;
    }

    // Never-before seen id card, append it to the result and set the key in $seen
    $filtered[] = $item;
    $seen[$item['id_card']] = TRUE;
  }

  return $filtered;
}
```

Note that this uses the map form of a PHP array, rather than just appending seen IDs to the list form and using something like `in_array` to check if we've seen the key. That's important for performance reasons, especially if we're going to be working on large datasets - `in_array` is O(n) with the # of items in the array whereas `array_key_exists` is O(1).

A more generic version of this function would look like this:

```
function filter_duplicate_field($data, $field) {
  $seen = array(); // To keep track of the keys we've seen
  $filtered = array(); // Will hold the result

  foreach($data as $item) {
    if(array_key_exists($item[$field], $seen)) {
      // We already encountered this key before.
      continue;
    }

    // Never-before seen key, append it to the result and set the key in $seen
    $filtered[] = $item;
    $seen[$item[$field]] = TRUE;
  }

  return $filtered;
}
```

You could then call it like `$result = filter_duplicate_field($data, 'id_card');`.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't preserve the original input order, but because the data is indexed so I'll assume that that doesn't matter.

With just 3 calls in a one-liner, you assign temporary associative keys from back to front to eliminate latter duplicates (because php does not permit duplicate keys), then optionally remove the temporary keys with `array_values()`.  No iterated function calls.  No lookup arrays.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/FRaMq))

```
$array = [
    ['id_card' => 11883834, 'type' => 1, 'registed' => 1547610891],
    ['id_card' => 20311077, 'type' => 1, 'registed' => 1547610891],
    ['id_card' => 16187903, 'type' => 3, 'registed' => 1547610891],
    ['id_card' => 16354099, 'type' => 1, 'registed' => 1547610891],
    ['id_card' => 21133393, 'type' => 4, 'registed' => 1547610891],
    ['id_card' => 15452852, 'type' => 2, 'registed' => 1547610891],
    ['id_card' => 19775869, 'type' => 2, 'registed' => 1547610891],
    ['id_card' => 20311077, 'type' => 1, 'registed' => 1547610891],
    ['id_card' => 21133393, 'type' => 4, 'registed' => 1547610891],
    ['id_card' => 11883834, 'type' => 1, 'registed' => 1547610891]
];

var_export(array_values(array_column(array_reverse($array), null, 'id_card')));
```

If you change you mind about wanting to keep the first occurrence, you can remove `array_reverse()`. If the first level keys are irrelevant in the output, you can remove `array_values()`. These changes would allow the solution to be a one function call task.

p.s. "regist**er**ed"

Comment: While this solution is clever and may also be efficient, it's not very readable - you'd want to accompany it in your code with a comment explaining what it's doing (or encapsulate it in a well-named function).

Comment: What I like about native functions is that they express what they do.

Comment: Do you honestly think someone will look at `var_export(array_values(array_column(array_reverse($array), null, 'id_card')));` and immediately think "removes duplicate ids"? I doubt it.

Comment: I am happy if someone wants to wrap my one-liner in a custom function or precede it with a comment block or declare 3 single-use variables.  You seem a bit edgy.  If this was my project, I'd probably not bother with 2 out of 3 of the function calls.

Comment: This doesn't need a function wrapper, just a good comment.  Nice tidy solution.